# MOSFET simulation using LTspice

Tags: mosfet, ac, dc

[image]
[image]
[image]

MOSFET, Im having some problem in the simulation for the input and output circuit, what I get was always a straight line

Comment: And if you simulate in another SPICE simulator, what happens?

Comment: Plot the voltage at the gate of the transistor. I don't think it is what you want it to be.

Comment: Why did you plot the drain current using transient analysis? Also, notice that your Vin for transient analysis is 0V. AC 10mV is for AC sweep analysis only and 6 is DC votlage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really take some notes, or follow some tutorials on basic SPICE usage. You'd see then that the source, as you have it, is not set up properly for your requirements: a sine with a frequency of 1 kHz (initially) and an amplitude of 10 mV, for `.TRAN` (as noted by [G36](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/574092/mosfet-simulation-using-ltspice/574112#comment1503698_574092)). Your value of `6 AC 10m` means the source is set up for an `.AC` analysis of 10 mV input with a 6 V offset. To correct it use: `SIN(0 10m 1k)`. There's no need for an offset because of `C1`.

Then you used `kp=0.8m`, instead of `0.4m`. Plus, `lambda` defaults to zero, so there's no need to write it in clear (but it won't hurt, either, it's just redundant).

Then, if you're not using any `.IC`, or `ic` flags, or any of `startup` or `uic`, then you're relying on LTspice to calculate the operating point, and it correctly determines it. Therefore you don't need to simulate for 3 seconds. Not lastly, a timestep of `0.01` is ten times the period of the signal, which means it's useless. Try `.tran 4m` (4 periods for a 1 kHz signal). Adapt accordingly as you change the frequency to 10 kHz and 100 kHz, respectively.

And, I shouldn't even say this, but probing the voltage is clearly marked in the schematic, in your problem context.

Answer (score 0):

> *Im having some problem in the simulation for the input and output
> circuit, what I get was always a straight line*

The input resistance to the MOSFET is set by R1 (40 MΩ) and R2 (10 MΩ). Together they have an effective AC resistance of R1 || R2 = 8 MΩ. Take note.

The input capacitor (Cc1) is 1 μF and this forms an effective time constant with the AC input resistance of 8 seconds. In other words, you need to run your simulation for a considerable length of time to get any stability in the output voltage. Try running for 30 seconds and see if it still flat-lines.

Or, set the initial conditions of the gate to be biased at 6 volts (30 volts divided by 5). Do you see why I chose 30 and 5?

Comment: Should i use transient, ac analysis or in the simulation. And at which point should I test because I still get a straight line.

Comment: Use transient analysis. If this doesn't work then show the transient analysis as a screen shot in your question. Maybe you should also show your simulated circuit.

Comment: I already upload back there on the post can u have a look. Thanks

Comment: You need to show the transient analysis picture too. Try it with dTmax set to a much smaller value also. Connect the MOSFET bulk pin to the source and not 0 volts. Indicate which node is flat-lined. Try simulating with an input of 1 volt peak not 10 mV.

Comment: I already upload the transient analysis I'm also not sure for the input at which point I should test.

Comment: Show the analysis on the node where you described it as "*I still get a straight line*". Clearly indicate what that node is on the schematic.

Comment: At the Vo point

Comment: Simulate it with 1 volt peak at the input. Your current picture indicates drain current - show the drain voltage and note that with 10 mV peak voltage, the drain current change will be about 8 uA and too small to see as a change in your current picture of drain current - probably smaller than 1 pixel!! Use a higher input voltage.

Comment: If you do an AC analysis it might help you to realize that there is a signal present on the output.